# Tried everything still getting error: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, instantiationexception

Whenever I try to open one of the activities (with the name `quizActivity`) in the app, the app crashes and gives the following error:

```
Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2020-08-17 21:41:20.561 12713-12713/inspire2connect.inspire2connect E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "inspire2connect.inspire2connect.whateverString" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/inspire2connect.inspire2connect-tnn4gqGg6Qg8JLYvyTp51A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/inspire2connect.inspire2connect-tnn4gqGg6Qg8JLYvyTp51A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:272)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:881)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:976)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1227)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2562)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2554)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6698)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:240)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7798)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
2020-08-17 21:41:20.880 12713-12777/inspire2connect.inspire2connect E/Perf: Fail to get file list inspire2connect.inspire2connect
2020-08-17 21:41:20.880 12713-12777/inspire2connect.inspire2connect E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Here is the link for the entire project:  [github.com/StealthViper/WashKaro](http://%20github.com/StealthViper/WashKaro)

I have been trying to see what the error is but can't seem to correct it. Most of the answers suggest something wrong with the manifest file but didn't work when I made those changes in my manifest file.
Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="inspire2connect.inspire2connect">
    
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name=".satyaChat.ChatActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".home.homeActivity" /> <!-- <activity android:name=".male_female_2" /> -->
        <activity android:name=".home.WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".survey.maleFemaleActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".news.text2speech2_2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".about.aboutActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".news.onAIrActivity" /> 

        <activity android:name=".mythGuidelineUpdates.UpdateActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".tweets.tweetActivity" />
        <activity android:name="inspire2connect.inspire2connect.quiz.quizActivity" />
        <activity android:name="inspire2connect.inspire2connect.quiz.scoreActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".utils.urlActivity" />

        <service
            android:name=".utils.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".mythGuidelineUpdates.guidelineViewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".home.InfographicsActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am also attaching my build.gradle file, as the error may be from there as indicated in some answers:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "inspire2connect.inspire2connect"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 24
        versionName "4.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Android & UI
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
//    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0"
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // Third Party
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
    implementation 'com.llollox:androidtoggleswitch:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.sefford:circular-progress-drawable:1.31@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
    implementation 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'

}
```

Here is the code for the quizActivity class:

```
public class quizActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 2399;
    TextView question, option1_text, option2_text, option3_text, option4_text,qCount,timer;
    ConstraintLayout[] options = new ConstraintLayout[4];
    public static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
    public static final String seen_questions_tag = "QuestionsShown";
    public ArrayList<questionObject> result;
    public ArrayList<questionObject> selected_questions;
    public ArrayList<questionObject> seen_questions;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private Dialog loadingDialog;
    private CountDownTimer countDown;
    private int quesNum;
    private int score;
    private boolean setDate;


    public void update_handle() {
        final AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo> () {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
                if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                    try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, quizActivity.this, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                    try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, quizActivity.this, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                Loge("UPDATE_STATUS", "Update flow failed! Result code: " + resultCode);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext( LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase));
    }


    private void setUpdates() {
        quizReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                result = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    questionObject obj = new questionObject (snapshot.child("question_"+ getCurLang()).getValue().toString(),snapshot.child("option1_"+ getCurLang ()).getValue().toString(),snapshot.child("option2_"+ getCurLang ()).getValue().toString(),snapshot.child("option3_"+ getCurLang ()).getValue().toString(),snapshot.child("option4_"+ getCurLang ()).getValue().toString(),Integer.valueOf ( snapshot.child ( "answer" ).getValue ().toString () ),snapshot.child("explanation_"+ getCurLang ()).getValue().toString(),snapshot.child("correct_attempts").getValue().toString (),snapshot.child("total_attempts").getValue().toString(), snapshot.getKey (),snapshot.child ( "key" ).getValue(Integer.class)  );

                    result.add(new questionObject (obj.question,
                            obj.option1,obj.option2,obj.option3,obj.option4, obj.answer,obj.explanation,obj.correct_attempts,obj.total_attempts, obj.id,obj.key));
                }

                selectQuestionSet(result);

                loadingDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setQuestion(){
        timer.setText ( String.valueOf ( 30 ) );

        question.setText ( selected_questions.get(0).getQuestion () );
        option1_text.setText ( selected_questions.get(0).getOption1 () );
        option2_text.setText ( selected_questions.get(0).getOption2 () );
        option3_text.setText ( selected_questions.get(0).getOption3 () );
        option4_text.setText ( selected_questions.get(0).getOption4 () );

        qCount.setText(String.valueOf(1) + "/" + String.valueOf(selected_questions.size()));

        startTimer();

        quesNum = 0 ;
    }

    private void startTimer()
    {
        countDown = new CountDownTimer (32000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(millisUntilFinished < 30000)
                    timer.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                changeQuestion();
            }
        };

        countDown.start();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStatusBarGradiant ( this );
        setContentView( R.layout.quiz_activity);

        question = findViewById ( R.id.question_text );
        qCount = findViewById ( R.id.quest_num );
        timer = findViewById(R.id.countdown);

        option1_text = findViewById ( R.id.option_1_text );
        option2_text = findViewById ( R.id.option_2_text );
        option3_text = findViewById ( R.id.option_3_text );
        option4_text = findViewById ( R.id.option_4_text );

        options[0] = findViewById ( R.id.option_1_tile );
        options[0].setOnClickListener ( this );
        options[1] = findViewById ( R.id.option_2_tile );
        options[1].setOnClickListener ( this );
        options[2] = findViewById ( R.id.option_3_tile );
        options[2].setOnClickListener ( this );
        options[3] = findViewById ( R.id.option_4_tile );
        options[3].setOnClickListener ( this );

        loadingDialog = new Dialog(quizActivity.this);
        loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_progressbar);
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        loadingDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.progress_background);
        loadingDialog.getWindow().setLayout( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        loadingDialog.show();

        setDate = false;

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT));

        Intent i = getIntent();

        String type = i.getStringExtra(TYPE);
        String date = i.getStringExtra(DATE);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext ());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(seen_questions);
        editor.putString(seen_questions_tag, json);
        editor.commit();

        switch (date) {
            case DATE_YES:
                setDate = true;
                break;
            default:
                setDate = false;
                break;
        }

        switch (type) {
            case UPDATES:
                databaseReference = governmentReference;
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.govt_updates_act);
                break;
            case GUIDELINES:
                databaseReference = guidelinesReference;
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.guidelines_act);
                break;
            case MYTH:
                databaseReference = mythReference;
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.myth_act);
                break;
            case FAQ:
                databaseReference = faqsReference;
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.faqs_tile);
                break;
            case SUCCESS_STORIES:
                databaseReference = successStoriesReference;
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.success_stories_tile);
                break;
            case TWEETS:
                databaseReference = tweetsReference;
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle( R.string.social_media_title);
                break;
            case QUIZ:
                databaseReference = quizReference;
                getSupportActionBar ().setTitle (getString( R.string.quiz_title));
                getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable ( Color.TRANSPARENT));
                break;
            default:
                Logv(TAG, "Invalid Intent");
                break;
        }

//        result = new ArrayList<>();
//        result.add(new questionObject ("No Question Available", "No Option Available","No Option Available","No Option Available","No Option Available",0,"No Data Available","No Data Available","No Data Available", "No Data Available",0));

        setUpdates();

        score = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int selectedOption = 0 ;

        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.option_1_tile :
                selectedOption = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.option_2_tile :
                selectedOption = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.option_3_tile :
                selectedOption = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.option_4_tile :
                selectedOption = 4;
                break;

            default:

        }
            countDown.cancel ();
            checkAnswer(selectedOption, view);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(int selectedOption, View view)
    {

        if(selectedOption == selected_questions.get(quesNum).getAnswer())
        {
            //Right Answer
            (view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
            quizReference.child ( selected_questions.get ( quesNum ).getId () ).child("correct_attempts").setValue( String.valueOf (Integer.valueOf (selected_questions.get ( quesNum ).getCorrect_attempts ())+1 ));
            quizReference.child ( selected_questions.get ( quesNum ).getId () ).child("total_attempts").setValue( String.valueOf (Integer.valueOf (selected_questions.get ( quesNum ).getTotal_attempts ())+1 ));
            score++;

        }
        else
        {
            //Wrong Answer
            (view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf( Color.RED));

            quizReference.child ( selected_questions.get ( quesNum ).getId() ).child("total_attempts").setValue( String.valueOf (Integer.valueOf (selected_questions.get ( quesNum ).getTotal_attempts ())+1 ));

            switch (selected_questions.get(quesNum).getAnswer ())
            {
                case 1:
                    options[0].setBackgroundTintList( ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    options[1].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    options[2].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    options[3].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    break;

            }

        }

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed( () -> changeQuestion(), 2000);



    }

    private void changeQuestion()
    {
        if( quesNum < selected_questions.size() - 1)
        {
            quesNum++;

            playAnim(question,0,0);
            playAnim(option1_text,0,1);
            playAnim(option2_text,0,2);
            playAnim(option3_text,0,3);
            playAnim(option4_text,0,4);

            qCount.setText(String.valueOf(quesNum+1) + "/" + String.valueOf(selected_questions.size()));

            timer.setText(String.valueOf(30));
            startTimer();

        }
        else
        {
            // Go to Score Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(quizActivity.this,scoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SCORE", String.valueOf(score) + "/" + String.valueOf(selected_questions.size()));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }


    }

    private void playAnim(final View view, final int value, final int viewNum)
    {

        view.animate().alpha(value).scaleX(value).scaleY(value).setDuration(500)
                .setStartDelay(100).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator ())
                .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        if(value == 0)
                        {
                            switch (viewNum)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    ((TextView)view).setText(selected_questions.get(quesNum).getQuestion());
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    ((TextView)view).setText(selected_questions.get(quesNum).getOption1 ());
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    ((TextView)view).setText(selected_questions.get(quesNum).getOption2 ());
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    ((TextView)view).setText(selected_questions.get(quesNum).getOption3 ());
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    ((TextView)view).setText(selected_questions.get(quesNum).getOption4 ());
                                    break;

                            }


                            if(viewNum != 0)
                                (view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#E99C03")));


                            playAnim(view,1,viewNum);

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        countDown.cancel();
    }




    public void selectQuestionSet(ArrayList<questionObject> result){

        try {
            selected_questions.clear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        Collections.sort(result);
        for (questionObject object: result) {
            if(selected_questions.size () < 5 && checkUsage(object.key) && checkLimit()){
                //display the question
                //append key to stored list
                selected_questions.add (object);
                seen_questions.add(object);
                SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext ());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(seen_questions);
                editor.putString(seen_questions_tag, json);
                editor.commit();

            }
            else if(selected_questions.size() < 5 && !checkLimit()) {
                seen_questions.clear();
                selectQuestionSet(result);
            }

            if(selected_questions.size () == 5){
                break;
            }


        }

        setQuestion ();
    }

    public boolean checkUsage(int key){
        //Check whether key already used or not here
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext ());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPrefs.getString(seen_questions_tag, "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<questionObject>> () {}.getType();
        List<questionObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        for (questionObject object : arrayList){
            if (object.key == key){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean checkLimit(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext ());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPrefs.getString(seen_questions_tag, "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<questionObject>> () {}.getType();
        List<questionObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        if(arrayList.size() > 95){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please share the code of your *quizActivity* class?

Comment: I have added it, it was quite big that's why I didn't add it earlier

Comment: Are you using Version Control?  Also add YOUR build.gradle file correctly

Comment: If you are using VCS then disable it & try Again

Comment: can you check one thing in manifest. 
<activity android:name="inspire2connect.inspire2connect.quiz.quizActivity" />
is the package correct? does ``ctrl+click`` takes it to the quizActivity.java class?

Comment: I have added the correct gradle file. Disabling VCS doesn't change anything I am still getting the same error

Comment: Yes it does take me to the quizActivity class

Comment: I really can't figure it out guys, any input will be really helpful

Comment: Did you try Build > Clean Project?   Also, Rebuild project?

Comment: I tried Clean project, but I haven't tried rebuilding the project. Will do that and let you know

Comment: tried it, still getting the same error. I remember I got something like a login screen while opening Android Studio for some license thing but i skipped that. I have been facing this problem after that only. Does that help? Also, I missed one line in the logcat in the beginning `GL_OOM reserved vma failed, errno:22`

Comment: This is the link for the entire project : https://github.com/StealthViper/WashKaro

Answer (score 1):

tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"

remove this from manifest file and go to file and click on the invalidate caches/restart

Comment: I am getting the error : Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(whateverString) from AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-53
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-66:19 to override.

Comment: I had the same problem & i don't know what to do on that time so I had make a new project and when you select empty activity after you can see that checkbox **Use lagacy android.support lib** click on it and migrate your project. i think you might think I'm mad but no I had tried and succeed

Comment: behind this error reason is your old lib config with each other and you will not able to find where & how so I think you have to try at least making a new project I hope it's works just like mine but yes if you have uploaded the app on playstore you might be lost your user because you are not able to replace the keystore credentials but check at least one time but not deleting your old project

Comment: How exactly do i migrate the original project after creating the new one?

Comment: Make a new one and replace your activity files and layout files with it and run it, check if it is working for you or not